# Flask-Socketio server on Google Cloud app engine flex env

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, flask, socket.io

I want to deploy a flask socketio server on app engine. This is the imports, and runs of the server:

```html
from typing import List
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, send, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, url_for
import sys
import numpy as np
import random
import re
import itertools

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port='8080', debug=True)
```

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
service: server

entrypoint: python3 main.py

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
```

I am using angular as a client, and it is connecting with this line:

```
this.socket = io('https://my-server-url.appspot.com');
```

When I try to run the angular app it says

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://server-url.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJu9Zq7' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also tried setting the cors_allowed_origins option to [] but it didn't work either.
I also tried setting session affinity to true and it didn't work either.

header is present on the requested resource.

I did not open the server url in another tab, and I want the server to run in the background.

Can you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.
I set the `session_affinity` to true and then I changed the `entrypoint` to:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app
```

App engine only works with the port of 8080.

Comment: Hi, could you explain the `eventlet` part... because when i use it in my flask app yaml it won't deploy.